# Wait inside ActionPerformed

Tags: java, swing

I want to wait inside this `actionPerfromed()` between `arr[1]=bot and try{...`

I have tried with `swing.timer` and `Thread.sleep()` but they do not work as i want. i will attach the whole program if you need it.

Thanks for your help.

[LINK](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/l391w6mqebl1316/AAAZXcKnvynGM1qURNhPxriZa?dl=0)

```
class pulsarBoton implements ActionListener,Serializable{
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        JButton bot=(JButton)e.getSource();
        if (arrBot[0]==null) {

            arrBot[0]=bot;
            arrBot[0].setIcon(new ImageIcon(arr.get(Integer.valueOf(bot.getName()))+".jpg"));//como puedo quitar el texto del boton pero referenciarlo al array??
        }else{
           bot.setIcon(new ImageIcon(arr.get(Integer.valueOf(bot.getName()))+".jpg"));
           arrBot[1]=bot;
           //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Continuar");
            try {
                //espera(4000);// --> IT DOES NOT WORK AS I WANT
                comprobar(arrBot);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(GUI.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null,     ex);
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(GUI.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null,     ex);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I tried this, but it does not work. Is it wrong??

```
class pulsarBoton implements ActionListener,Serializable{
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        JButton bot=(JButton)e.getSource();
        if (arrBot[0]==null) {
            arrBot[0]=bot;
            arrBot[0].setIcon(new ImageIcon(arr.get(Integer.valueOf(bot.getName()))+".jpg"));//como puedo quitar el texto del boton pero referenciarlo al array??
        }else{
           bot.setIcon(new ImageIcon(arr.get(Integer.valueOf(bot.getName()))+".jpg"));
           arrBot[1]=bot;
           //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Continuar");
           //espera(4000);// --> IT DOES NOT WORK AS I WANT
            try {
                Timer tiempo=new Timer(3000, new timerPerformed());
                tiempo.start();
                comprobar(arrBot);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(GUI.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(GUI.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    }
}

class timerPerformed implements ActionListener{

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        System.out.println("A");
    }

}
```

Comment: Why?  Use a Swing `Timer` set to a delay of `4000` which when called calls `comprobar(arrBot);`.  You can't block the EDT, otherwise the UI will stop responding. See [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) and [How to use Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) for more details

Comment: I tried it but does not work. Maybe i wrote it in bad line. I updated the post.

Comment: Move `comprobar(arrBot);` into `actionPerformed` of `timerPerformed`

Comment: You are right men. Thank you very much!!!

Comment: Well, that makes a nice change ;)